# How to combine cells from two separate data sheets with specific requests using vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have started to write a vba script to merge datas from two separate sheets using some conditions I need. The code is not finished, as I don't know how to proceed next from this, and I'm sure there is a much better, simpler solution to this. First my code:

```
 Sub test()
Dim RD As Range
Set RD = Worksheets("TEST").Range("A1:A3")
With RD
    .TextToColumns Comma:=True, DataType:=xlDelimited
End With

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xOut As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim xTemp As Variant
Dim xStr As Variant
On Error Resume Next

Set WorkRng = Worksheets("TEST").Range("A1:C3")
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    xOut = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(Rng.Value)
        xTemp = Mid(Rng.Value, i, 1)
        If xTemp Like "[0-9]" Then
            xStr = xTemp
        Else
            xStr = ""
        End If
        xOut = xOut & xStr
    Next i
    Rng.Value = xOut
Next

Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range
Dim rowIndex As Integer

Set Range1 = Worksheets("TEST").Range("A1:C3")
Set Range2 = Worksheets("TEST").Range("A8")
rowIndex = 0
For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
    Rng.Copy
    Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Columns.Count
Next

Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0

For i = 1 To 20
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(counter + 1, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I have two separate datas on two sheets. I would like to merge them together somehow. Here is the data:

```
Sheet1                                  Sheet2
A          B                            A          B
8.2.2021   21009                        328598     41520 (Ottawa)
           21031                        326548     41940 (Washington), 41540 (London), 48950 (Sydney)
8.2.2021   41940                        325685     21009 (New York), 21031 (Tokyo)
           41540                        325614     41520 (Ottawa)
           48950
8.2.2021   41520                
8.2.2021   41520
```

On Sheet1, the first one has dates (column A) and some codes for the stores (Column B). On Sheet2, the second one has the required order numbers for them (column A), and the stores too, but in a different format (Column B). I would want to merge them together in a way, that the order numbers from Sheet2, put beside the other 2 Columns (so into Column C), of course into their corresponding rows, into a row which contains the order date (in Column A) . (See the third table on how it should look like.) Please notice how there could be multiple rows with identical stores, but different order numbers.

If thats the case, and if they have the same order day (Column A Table 1), then the one thing, which is important, is that they need to have different order numbers (Column B Table 2). Otherwise, they will have a different order day (Column A Table 1).

This is how its supposed to look like in the end:

```
A          B      C
8.2.2021   21009  325685
           21031  
8.2.2021   41940  326548
           41540
           48950
8.2.2021   41520  328598
8.2.2021   41520  325614
```

My code splits the second table Column B into different cells, removes the letters, so only the store numbers remain, then puts them into a single column. I dont know If Im on the right path on solving this though. It looks like this when the code finishes:

```
Sheet1                    Sheet2
A          B              A          B          
8.2.2021   21009          328598     41520
           21031          326548     41940
8.2.2021   41940          325685     41540
           41540          325614     48950
           48950                     21009
8.2.2021   41520                     21031
8.2.2021   41520                     41520
```

Comment: you just need to copy down Sheet2.A when you occupy more rows for B. After that, use vlookup to bring the values to Sheet1

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` as a way to suppress all runtime errors is not a good idea. It is like throwing away a smoke alarm because you don't like it when it beeps. Much better to fix the cause of the smoke.

Comment: Why are the values corresponding to the last two lines 41520 different as 328598 and 325614?

Comment: There could be two different orders from the same store (in this example,Ottawa). They have different order numbers if thats the case. (Sheet 2 Column A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to extract the store numbers and a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) with the store as a key and an collection of order numbers as the values.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
    Dim Regex As Object
    Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With Regex
       .Global = True
       .MultiLine = False
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Pattern = "\d+" ' any digits
    End With

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim i As Long, n As Integer, s As String, ar As Variant
    Dim c As Collection
    Dim sStore As String, sOrder As String, sLastOrder As String
    
    ' scan sheet 2 column b to fill dictionary
    For i = 1 To ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        sOrder = ws2.Cells(i, "A")
        s = ws2.Cells(i, "B")
        If Regex.test(s) Then
            Set ar = Regex.Execute(s)
            For n = 1 To ar.Count
                sStore = CStr(ar.Item(n - 1))
                If dict.exists(sStore) Then
                    dict(sStore).Add sOrder
                Else
                    Set c = New Collection
                    c.Add sOrder
                    dict.Add sStore, c
                End If
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox "No stores in " & s, vbCritical, ws2.Name & " row " & i
        End If
    Next
    
   ' scan stores in sheet 1 col B and fill in column C with orders
    For i = 1 To ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        sStore = ws1.Cells(i, "B")
        If dict.exists(sStore) Then
            ' check there are orders for this store
            If dict(sStore).Count > 0 Then
                sOrder = dict(sStore).Item(1)
                ' don't repeat
                If sOrder <> sLastOrder Then
                    ws1.Cells(i, "C") = sOrder
                End If
                dict(sStore).Remove (1)
                sLastOrder = sOrder
            Else
                MsgBox "No orders left for store " & sStore, vbCritical, ws1.Name & " Row " & i
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "No orders for store " & sStore, vbCritical, ws1.Name & " Row " & i
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Finished"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Work's like it should be. I just modified for myself the columns from where it reads the data.